# Need to move the last line of the file to second line of the same file

Tags: text-processing, files

I have a file 'test' in linux with below data.

```
aaaaaa
bbbbbb
cccccc
dddddd
eeeeee
```

I need to cut the last line of this file and put it in the second position. It must look like below.

```
aaaaaa
eeeeee
bbbbbb
cccccc
dddddd
```

Answer (score 9):

This problem might actually be easiest to do with `ed`, since it's a basically a scriptable text editor, rather than a stream processor.  Using `ed`, you don't have to save all the lines of the file into an array, for instance, since it's already doing that for you.

```
# Create test file
~> printf "%s\n" aaaaaa bbbbbb cccccc dddddd eeeeee >test.txt
~> cat test.txt
aaaaaa
bbbbbb
cccccc
dddddd
eeeeee

# Use ed to open the file, move the last line after the first, save, and quit
~> printf "%s\n" '$m1' wq | ed test.txt
35
35
~> cat test.txt
aaaaaa
eeeeee
bbbbbb
cccccc
dddddd
```

Answer (score 5):

### Hold buffer method:

```
sed '$x;1!H;1p;$!d;x;s/\n//
' <<\IN
aaaaaa
bbbbbb
cccccc
dddddd
eeeeee
IN
```

...that will `H`old every line which is `!`not the first, and the first it `p`rints. On the `$`last line it e`x`changes hold and pattern spaces *before* it does the `H`old - which gets the saved lines appended to the last line - then `d`eletes from output all lines which are `!`not the `$`last.

On the `$`last line it e`x`changes spaces again, `s///`ubstitutes away the first `\n`ewline character - which takes care of the extra added on line 2 - then autoprints the lot.

#### OUTPUT:

```
aaaaaa
eeeeee
bbbbbb
cccccc
dddddd
```

### without using the Hold buffer:

```
cat <<\IN >infile
aaaaaa
bbbbbb
cccccc
dddddd
eeeeee
IN
```

...just to save your example into an actual file...

```
sed '1p;$!d;r infile' <infile | sed '3d;$d'
```

That redirects `<infile` to the first `sed`'s `stdin`, which only `p`rints the first line before `d`eleting from output all lines which are `!`not the `$`last. The last line is autoprinted, but it is also the only line on which the final command is executed - which is to `r`ead out the entire `infile` *again* to `stdout`. All of that gets passed over the `|`pipe to the second `sed` which then has only to `d`elete from its output its third and final input lines to complete the rearrange.

#### OUTPUT:

```
aaaaaa
eeeeee
bbbbbb
cccccc
dddddd
```

Comment: cool, +1. I don't recall you ever posting `awk` solutions, are you a huge `sed` fan or perhaps you wrote `sed`? ;-)

Comment: @1_CR - i dunno how to use `awk` - i've never tried. maybe someday...

Answer (score 2):

A naive approch using awk:

```
~$ awk '{a[NR]=$0}END{print a[1];print a[NR];for(i=2;i<NR;i++){print a[i]}}' f
aaaaaa
eeeeee
bbbbbb
cccccc
dddddd
```

You store every line in the `a` array, then print the array in the order you want (1st line, last one (`NR`) and from 2 to penultimate.

Using a combination of head/tail and sed:

```
~$ head -1 f;tail -1 f;sed '1d;$d' f
aaaaaa
eeeeee
bbbbbb
cccccc
dddddd
```

Print the first line, the last, and with sed delete the 1st and last.

---

With sed only, I have only been able to find this command. I am sure there are better ways:

```
~$ sed '${p;x;s/^\n//;p};2,${H;d}' f
aaaaaa
eeeeee
bbbbbb
cccccc
dddddd
```

If it's the first line, print it (default).
From the second line, put it in the hold buffer(`H`), and delete in from the pattern space (`d`). 
And if it's the last line, print it (`p`), then get the hold buffer (`x`), delete the empty line (`s/^\n//`) and print it (`p`).

Comment: My first instinct would be to use the head/tail method. An alternative to the `sed` part would be something like `head -n -1 f | tail -n +2`.

Comment: @Sparhawk the `-1` syntax for `head` there is not portable.

Answer (score 1):

With perl :

```
perl -e 'my @lines = <>; print for @lines[0, $#lines, 1..$#lines-1]' file
```

With awk :

```
$ awk '
    {lines[NR]=$0}
    END{
        print lines[1], lines[NR];
        for (i=2; i<NR; i++) {print lines[i]}
    }
' OFS=$'\n' file
```

**OUTPUT**

```
aaaaaa
eeeeee
bbbbbb
cccccc
dddddd
```