# sed: cut line X and append to top of the file

Tags: sed, awk

I would like to be able to cut line X and insert the line X on position y (top).
This would help me to be able to reorganize some config files.

```
Text example line number 1 <--- Append line 10 above line 1
Text example line number 2
Text example line number 3
Text example line number 4
Text example line number 5
Text example line number 6
Text example line number 7
Text example line number 8
Text example line number 9
Text example line number 10 <--- Cut or hold in buffer
Text example line number 11
Text example line number 12
Text example line number 13
```

so far the only thing I have found is:

```
# Cuts line 10 and adds it to the end of file    
sed -n -e '10h;10!p;${g;p;}' file-01.txt
```

But I don't know how to place the hold content on another line than the last.

Unfortunately I'm not so familiar with sed. There are similar questions on stackoverflow and here but I was not able to modify them to meet my needs.

I would prefer a solution with sed but if it can be achieved easier with other tools like awk than this solutions are also welcome.

Comment: See [Need to move the last line of the file to second line of the same file](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/173948). I recommend `ed` for this job.

Comment: `sed -n '10p' file > newfile; sed '10d' file >> newfile`

Comment: @Cyrus: Like your solution. To do it inplace, we can do this after your command. ; mv newfilw file-01.txt

Comment: @don_crissti Thanks for the hint. Surprisingly I never stumbled across this thread.

Comment: @Cyrus Its a nice and easy solution and with the last step mentioned by CHID  it solves my issue completely. Thanks guys!

Comment: @caracal: Maybe your sed has option `-i` to edit "in place".

Comment: @Cyrus Oh yes my sed has the option `-i`. I am aware of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Using sed

Let's create a test file:

```
$ seq 10 >file
```

To move, say, line 5 to the top of a file:

```
$ sed '1,4{H;1h;d}; 5{p;x}' file
5
1
2
3
4
6
7
8
9
10
```

#### How it works

- `1,4{H;1h;d}`

  This saves lines 1 through 4 in the hold space.

  In more detail, `H` appends the current line to the hold space after appending a newline to the hold space.  For line 1, we don't want that newline, so we issue the command `1h` which sends line 1 to the hold space with no newline.  The `d` command deletes the current line from the pattern space so that it doesn't get printed yet.
- `5{p;x}`

  This prints line 5 and then prints the hold space.  `p` tells sed to print the pattern space (which contains line 5).  `x` tells sed to put to swap the pattern and hold space so that what was in the hold space will now be printed.

Lines after line 5 are passed through unchanged.

### Using awk

```
$ awk 'NR<5{s=s ORS $0;next} NR==5{print $0 s;next} 1' file
5
1
2
3
4
6
7
8
9
10
```

The logic here is quite similar to that for sed.  We save all lines before line 5 in the variable `s`.  When we reach line 5, we print it followed by s.  The remaining lines are passed through unchanged.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your solution is my favorite. I like the sed solution and thank you for the explanation, it helps me a lot to understand sed better. The awk solution is as well very handy. awk is going to be my next learning step...