# How to move the last line in a file?

Tags: text-processing

Example of a file

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
```

`line 4` should be after `line 1`

```
line 1
line 4
line 2
line 3
```

Important: It could be more than 4 lines somehow the script has to understand that it has to read the last line, **not** line 4.

Comment: Not very effective but it works with GNU sed: `sed '1!d' file; sed '$!d' file; sed -n '2,${$d;p}' file`

Comment: Bash isn’t a text editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative, slower, longer version.

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ ! -f "$1" ]
then
    printf "No input file\n"
    exit
fi

FIRST=`head -n 1 "${1}"`
LAST=`tail -n 1 "${1}"`
MID=`sed -n '$d; 2,$p' "${1}"`
printf "${FIRST}\n${LAST}\n${MID}\n"

exit
```

Slower because using `head`, `tail` and `sed` to access the file each time. On a large file (or many files) this could be very noticeable.

Comment: The `sed` pipeline could be shortened into `sed -n '$d; 2,$p'`

Comment: @Kusalananda - Thanks, updated. The answers on the [linked duplicate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/173948/need-to-move-the-last-line-of-the-file-to-second-line-of-the-same-file) are way better. This must be some kind of test question.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ printf '4m1\n,p\n' | ed -s file
line 1
line 4
line 2
line 3
```

The short `ed` script

```
4m1
,p
```

will move line four to after line one, and then display the contents of the editing buffer in the terminal.

To save the result to a new file, you may use a redirection like

```
printf '4m1\n,p\n' | ed -s file >newfile
```

or you may tell `ed` to save the file with

```
printf '4m1\nw newfile\n' | ed -s file
```

The command `w newfile` would save the edited buffer into the named file.  The command `w` with no filename would save the file back to the original filename.

Since the line editor `ed` reads the file into memory, it is okay to use it for this kind of thing if the file is of reasonable but not too large size (less than gigabytes).

---

To move the *last* line, change `4` to `$` in the commands above.